# push message from server to smart phone

Tags: android, rest, server, push-notification

I am planning to construct below system.

smart phone1 - server - smart phone2

In this system Phone 1 sends the data to the server(using rest api),
then server forwards it to Phone 2(using fcm based http).

I surfed the internet and I saw the above statement, but I do not know why.

So my questions are,

1.Is it possible to implement the system as described above?

2.I am wondering why I use rest api to send the data.
If I use fcm (based XMPP) to send the data to the server, will there be a problem??

I'm a beginner. I'm sorry to ask simple question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called Push Notification services, [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) (Firebase Cloud Messaging) is exactly what you want, there are many other services that provide this thing like [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/).

These services give you a unique id for every user of your application, so you can store user id's in you server database and identify each user with that id.

All you need to do is send a HTTP request to your server that contains the data and the target user id (Phone 2 in your example), and your server sends a request to the Push Notification service to send the data to the target user and user receives it.

And in case you want to avoid using RESTapi, you have to send your requests directly from Phone 1 to Push Notification service, it's possible for developing a personal application, but it's strongly not recommended for releasing applications, because as i said before, every user has a unique id and you need to store them in some where that you can access them on every client, and you need a server for doing this.

So you need to learn about RESTapi and after that, follow your Push Notification provider guidelines.

Comment: I commented before and it disappeared.
Thank you very much for your reply.
I completely understood it. It really helped me a lot.